# nginx.conf VS configuration inside sites-enabled?

Tags: nginx, configuration, server

Noob question here :

Whats the difference between the configuration inside nginx.conf and those inside the sites-enabled directory? Which takes precedence?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sites-enabled" directory keeps your virtual hosts configurations. The nginx.conf keeps your nginx configuration + the virtual host configs. 
Example from a nginx.conf file:

```
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```